# how to save the binary of image of multi part form in node js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, nodejs-stream

[upload image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfkqa.png)I am trying to make upload image in pure nodejs, please don't ask me why you do that cuz I am obliged to make it in pure node js I parsed the request header and I checked about image uploading or any files and I have in the console these bytes of image req data. and I**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3pXP.png)** am tried to save it with fs module and the image saved successfully but when opening it gives me "this file format can't be opened"

how can i save the uploaded image ??

Comment: hi can you share code to see whats going on ?